# How to make this code dynamic

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to make this code dynamic i.e in place of n_numb number := 1990 if i enter a different year it should execute based on that year you enter.

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON

declare

  v_test varchar2(80) := 'BORN';
  n_numb number := 1990;
begin

  while v_test <> 'Birthday' 
 loop 
      if    n_numb = 1991 then v_test := 'Birthday';
      end if;
    dbms_output.put_line (v_test||': '||n_numb);
    n_numb := n_numb + 1;
  end loop;

 v_test := 'Playschool';
  while n_numb < 1994 AND v_test = 'Playschool' loop
     dbms_output.put_line (v_test||': '||n_numb);
      n_numb := n_numb + 1;
 end loop;

 v_test := 'Regularschool';
  while n_numb < 2007 AND v_test = 'Regularschool' loop
     dbms_output.put_line (v_test||': '||n_numb);
      n_numb := n_numb + 1;
 end loop;

  v_test := 'Engineering';
  while n_numb < 2011 AND v_test = 'Engineering' loop
     dbms_output.put_line (v_test||': '||n_numb);
      n_numb := n_numb + 1;
 end loop;

  v_test := 'SearchingJob';
  while n_numb < 2013 AND v_test = 'SearchingJob' loop
     dbms_output.put_line (v_test||': '||n_numb);
      n_numb := n_numb + 1;
 end loop;

  v_test := 'Working';
  while n_numb < 2014 AND v_test = 'Working' loop
     dbms_output.put_line (v_test||': '||n_numb);
      n_numb := n_numb + 1;
 end loop;
 end;
```

Comment: You can create a procedure and pass the year as parameter.

Comment: currently its not working we change the year, first we need to fix the error in the code.

Comment: what is the error in the code?

Comment: What is the purpose of just printing some messages to screen?

Comment: If you type any other year in place of n_numb number := 1990 it should do the calculation and print the output

Comment: What is the calculation that you want to do? `n_numb+1 = 'Birthday'`, `n_numb+2 = 'Playschool'`, etc?

Comment: if i enter any year in place of 1990 as date of birth it should print for 1st year his birthday,after 4 years playschool,after 8 years school,15 years college etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this code take a year input and print out based on the years elapsed, you will need to switch from changing the activity based on *year-number* to *years-accumulated*.

I'll add a couple examples below.
The first will modify your original code to allow switching `n_numb`.
The second will refactor to use `procedure`s to simplify things.

For a first example, I'll start with your original code, and add an `accumulator` `V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION` to measure the years.  Then changing `n_numb` to different values will get a different output.

```
DECLARE
  V_TEST VARCHAR2(80) := 'BORN';
  N_NUMB NUMBER := 1990;
  V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

  WHILE V_TEST <> 'Birthday'
  LOOP
    IF V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION = 1
    THEN V_TEST := 'Birthday';
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(V_TEST || ': ' || N_NUMB);
    N_NUMB := N_NUMB + 1;
    V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION := V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION + 1;
  END LOOP;

  V_TEST := 'Playschool';
  WHILE V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION < 4 AND V_TEST = 'Playschool' LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(V_TEST || ': ' || N_NUMB);
    N_NUMB := N_NUMB + 1;
    V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION := V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION + 1;
  END LOOP;

  V_TEST := 'Regularschool';
  WHILE V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION < 17 AND V_TEST = 'Regularschool' LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(V_TEST || ': ' || N_NUMB);
    N_NUMB := N_NUMB + 1;
    V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION := V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION + 1;
  END LOOP;

  V_TEST := 'Engineering';
  WHILE V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION < 21 AND V_TEST = 'Engineering' LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(V_TEST || ': ' || N_NUMB);
    N_NUMB := N_NUMB + 1;
    V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION := V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION + 1;
  END LOOP;

  V_TEST := 'SearchingJob';
  WHILE V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION < 23 AND V_TEST = 'SearchingJob' LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(V_TEST || ': ' || N_NUMB);
    N_NUMB := N_NUMB + 1;
    V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION := V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION + 1;
  END LOOP;

  V_TEST := 'Working';
  WHILE V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION < 24 AND V_TEST = 'Working' LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(V_TEST || ': ' || N_NUMB);
    N_NUMB := N_NUMB + 1;
    V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION := V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

And test it:

using `n_numb := 1990` gives:

```
BORN: 1990
Birthday: 1991
Playschool: 1992
Playschool: 1993
Regularschool: 1994
...
...
SearchingJob: 2012
Working: 2013
```

but with `n_numb := 1899`, you get:

```
BORN: 1899
Birthday: 1900
Playschool: 1901
Playschool: 1902
Regularschool: 1903
```

But, there is some refactoring that can simplify things.
In this second example, I'll create procedures to do the printing and move from one activity to the next as the years proceed.  This will require less code.

First, create a procedure to `print` the current `activity` and progress the `years`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GROW_OLDER(P_ACTIVITY IN VARCHAR2, P_YEARS_TO_CONTINUE IN NUMBER, P_YEARS_ACCUMULATED IN OUT NUMBER)
IS
  V_LOCAL_ACCUMULATION NUMBER := 0;
  BEGIN
    WHILE V_LOCAL_ACCUMULATION < P_YEARS_TO_CONTINUE LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('%s: %s',P_ACTIVITY,TO_CHAR(P_YEARS_ACCUMULATED + V_LOCAL_ACCUMULATION)));
      V_LOCAL_ACCUMULATION := V_LOCAL_ACCUMULATION + 1;
      END LOOP;
    P_YEARS_ACCUMULATED := P_YEARS_ACCUMULATED + P_YEARS_TO_CONTINUE;
  END;
/
```

Then create a procedure to orchestrate the movement from activity to activity across the years:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MOVE_THROUGH_THE_YEARS(P_START_YEAR IN NUMBER)
IS
  V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION NUMBER := P_START_YEAR;
  BEGIN
    GROW_OLDER('Born', 1, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('Birthday', 1, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('Playschool', 2, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('Regularschool', 13, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('Engineering', 4, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('SearchingJob', 2, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('Working', 1, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
  END;
/
```

Then Test it.  Starting `1990`:

```
BEGIN
  MOVE_THROUGH_THE_YEARS(1990);
END;
/

Born: 1990
Birthday: 1991
Playschool: 1992
Playschool: 1993
Regularschool: 1994
Regularschool: 1995
...
...
Engineering: 2010
SearchingJob: 2011
SearchingJob: 2012
Working: 2013
```

Or `2077`:

```
BEGIN
  MOVE_THROUGH_THE_YEARS(2077);
END;
/

Born: 2077
Birthday: 2078
Playschool: 2079
Playschool: 2080
Regularschool: 2081
Regularschool: 2082
...
...
Engineering: 2097
SearchingJob: 2098
SearchingJob: 2099
Working: 2100
```

**EDIT**  If you only want to print each activity once, you can replace the `GROW_OLDER` procedure above with an alternative that does no looping.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GROW_OLDER(P_ACTIVITY IN VARCHAR2, P_YEARS_TO_CONTINUE IN NUMBER, P_YEARS_ACCUMULATED IN OUT NUMBER)
IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('%s: %s',P_ACTIVITY,TO_CHAR(P_YEARS_ACCUMULATED)));
    P_YEARS_ACCUMULATED := P_YEARS_ACCUMULATED + P_YEARS_TO_CONTINUE;
  END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MOVE_THROUGH_THE_YEARS(P_START_YEAR IN NUMBER)
IS
  V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION NUMBER := P_START_YEAR;
  BEGIN
    GROW_OLDER('Born', 1, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('Birthday', 1, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('Playschool', 2, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('Regularschool', 13, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('Engineering', 4, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('SearchingJob', 2, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
    GROW_OLDER('Working', 1, V_YEAR_ACCUMULATION);
  END;
/
```

Then test it:

```
BEGIN
  MOVE_THROUGH_THE_YEARS(1990);
END;
  /
```

Result:

```
Born: 1990
Birthday: 1991
Playschool: 1992
Regularschool: 1994
Engineering: 2007
SearchingJob: 2011
Working: 2013
```

**Edit** If you need an anonymous block with one row per activity, here's an example:

```
DECLARE
  V_YEARS NUMBER := 1990;
  BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('Born: '||TO_CHAR(V_YEARS)));
  V_YEARS := V_YEARS + 1;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('Birthday: '||TO_CHAR(V_YEARS)));
  V_YEARS := V_YEARS + 1;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('Playschool: '||TO_CHAR(V_YEARS)));
  V_YEARS := V_YEARS + 2;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('Regularschool: '||TO_CHAR(V_YEARS)));
  V_YEARS := V_YEARS + 13;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('Engineering: '||TO_CHAR(V_YEARS)));
  V_YEARS := V_YEARS + 4;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('SearchingJob: '||TO_CHAR(V_YEARS)));
  V_YEARS := V_YEARS + 2;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(UTL_LMS.FORMAT_MESSAGE('Working: '||TO_CHAR(V_YEARS)));
  V_YEARS := V_YEARS + 1;
END;
/
```

Output is same as all the other examples:

```
Born: 1990
Birthday: 1991
Playschool: 1992
Regularschool: 1994
Engineering: 2007
SearchingJob: 2011
Working: 2013
```

Comment: What if i don't want the output repeating like BORN: 1987
Birthday: 1988
Playschool: 1989
Regularschool: 1991
Engineering: 2004
SearchingJob: 2008
Working: 2010

Comment: Thanks @RaviTej Sure thing you can print once per activity.  I'll update with an example.

Comment: @RaviTej I added another example that only prints one line per activity at the bottom of the post.  Is this what you were looking for?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks you for the solution but is there a way to do the whole solution without using procedure i.e only loops and get the above output?

Comment: @RaviTej sure thing there's a way. If you don't want to compile anything and only want one line per activity, you can just increment the accumulated years and print the activity; no looping is necessary if you only want one line per activity. You can combine the first example that doesn't use a procedure and has v_year_accumulation with the general idea of what the procedure is doing--increment and print--in one block, repeating for each activity. Is that what you were aiming for?  Just let me know if you would like an example of that. Thanks

Comment: Yes exactly that's what i'm looking for, can you do that for the same logic above.

Comment: @RaviTej I added another example at the end of the post.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes that's it. Thank You